# Action.setCallback not being executed event tabclosed lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, controller

I have an issue where in my action.setCallBack is not being run.

When user closes the tab, the component call a function onTabClosed.

```
onTabClosed : function(component, event, helper) {
    var aCaseId = component.get("v.recordId");
       console.log('yep');
    var action = component.get("c.hasCustomerInteractionOpen");        
    action.setParams({aCaseId : aCaseId});        
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        console.log('callBack');
        
    var state = response.getState();
    var result = response.getReturnValue();
    //console.log('BKO Picklist values ' +JSON.stringify(result));
  
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        console.log('test1');
            component.set("v.checkTab",true);


    }
    else{
        console.log('test2');
        component.set("v.checkTab",true);
    } 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);   

    console.log('yep1');

},
```

The console.log inside callBack is not being executed. Only the console.log(yep1) and (yep2).

Here is the Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean hasCustomerInteractionOpen(String aCaseId){

    try{
        Case lCase = [SELECT AttendanceProtocol__c, Id, Status, AttendanceProtocol__r.LastModifiedDate, AttendanceProtocol__r.vlocity_cmt__Status__c, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id =: aCaseId LIMIT 1];

        if((String.isNotBlank(lCase.AttendanceProtocol__c)) && (lCase.AttendanceProtocol__r.vlocity_cmt__Status__c != 'Closed') && (lCase.OwnerId == (UserInfo.getUserId()))){
            List<Case> lCaseCustomer = [SELECT Id,AttendanceProtocol__c, Status, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE AttendanceProtocol__c =: lCase.AttendanceProtocol__c 
            ORDER BY ClosedDate DESC];
            if((lCaseCustomer[0].Id == lCase.Id) && ((lCase.AttendanceProtocol__r.LastModifiedDate) < (lCaseCustomer[0].ClosedDate))){
                System.debug('true');
                return true;
            }

        }
        System.debug('false');
        return false;

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        return false;

    }
  
}
```

The system.debug is returning in the debugging. So, the apex is being called, returning a value.

But the action.setCallBack is not accessing this value. I'm on it has two days, someone can help me? Really appreciate it.